# Is there an option to make TeamCity clone a Mercurial repository with minimal processing instead of init/pull?

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, waitress, kallithea

We have an old TeamCity server that uses an old Kallithea on Windows. One of our projects has become relatively big and now only clonable with "--stream" option. Without it the "remote host closes connection". Kallitheas WSGI server (Waitress) seems to be responsible for this. I can only set "asyncore_loop_timeout" there, which makes no difference.

Is it possible to configure TeamCity to clone with "--stream" instead of using init and pull?

I would not be sad about another possible solution either. :)

Answer (score 0):

(I made a copy of the project repository and Team City project.)

I have detached and removed the VCS root.

I inserted a Command Line build step on 1st position:

`hg clone --verbose --stream http://username:password@hg-server/project-name`

I had to insert the project directory to all paths.

I now get the build artifacts.

**Some problems:** I had to define build.vcs.number and branch name as parameters (seems they are normally taken from VCS root). I just set them to '1'. The commit hook doesn't work and no change log is displayed. I'll leave it this way until I move to git someday on a new server...

Probably more problems will arise. I will add them here.